# Bootstap Dropdown Menu Margin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with the CSS of my Bootstrap dropdown menu for my web app. It is too far to the right edge of the page for my liking, and I would simply like it to be shifted to the left a bit more. I have tried to style the menu with a margin-right in order to get it off the edge of the screen, but still no luck even though if I do the same with margin-left, it moves the menu even farther off the right edge of the screen. I need some assistance with the CSS on this issue.  Below is what the menu looks like:

[image: original]

I simply have given an ID "dropdownMenu" to the dropdown, and it is being applied to the correct HTML element, but the margin-right is simply not working. Here is the accompanying HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            More <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="${contextRoot}/profile">
                    Account
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:$('#logoutForm').submit();">
                    Sign Out
                 </a>
            </li>
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="${contextRoot}/register">
                        Register
                    </a>
                </li>
            </sec:authorize>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
#dropdownMenu {
    margin-right: 2% !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set `position: relative` to component style ?

Comment: I just tried this. This does allow me to shift the menu, but it also moves the "More" word itself. I've pasted the HTML above, as well as the CSS that I've added.

Comment: inspect the floating element in order to get more details and apply the style modifications to that specific container

Comment: it is possible to see the URL where you applied this Bootstrap menu?

Comment: I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original CSS for Bootstrap dropdown-menu class has property left:0. I altered this, and the final placement I liked was left:-10px; You see in the image the menu is no longer on the edge.                                                                                                                                                                               [image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

You can try for example `margin-right: 20px !important`.
`!important` will gonna apply the margin right to your element because it will gonna override the old value.

Comment: Have you tried applying the mr class of bootstrap. Example : mr-3

Comment: I've posted my final solution above.